# Year is to Annualized; as Day is to _____?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, phrases, synonyms

Is there such a word exists to fill in this analogy: Is there such a word exists to fill in this analogy: Year is to Annualized; as Day is to _____ ?

Daily comes to mind but not really correct.

Other contenders: Diurnalized, Quotidianized

Comment: It would be nice if "journalized" could be used in this context, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Thinking of it as happening or occurring yearly/annually, how about the analogy "Year is to Annually; as Day is to Daily" — if it does not have to follow the "ed" ending. 
Hope it would help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [*diurnal*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/diurnal)? It means of the day or during the day. I think this might be exactly what you are looking for, but this is by no means a common word in English.

[Example](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/home/environment/global-warming/mild-winters-may-be-the-new-normal-says-study/articleshow/56768976.cms) I pulled off the Web:

> There is a negative trend in the **diurnal** temperature range during the end of the century, which indicates that the minimum temperatures are warming faster than the maximum temperatures.

Comment: Annualized does no mean yearly, more like "equivalent to yearly". For example, you might have a 0.4% monthly interest rate which *annualized* would be equivalent to 4.8% interest rate (assuming simple interest, just multiply by 12). Diurnal does no convey this. Moreover, diurnal is often opposed to nocturnal, so instead of meaning 24 hours it might mean those hours in which there is light.